# Unauthorized 401 in angular4

Tags: angular, http-post

I try to post data to server but I have this error:

[image]

code post:

```
addBike(data) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
    headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+ authToken);
    headers.append('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Authorization');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    console.log(headers.get('Authorization'));
    this.http.post('link api',data,{headers: headers,responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res => console.log(res),err=> console.log(err));
}
```

I add token to Authorization but also error and when I show headers in console:

[image]

Comment: i think headers.append overwrite headers. you can use headers.set

Answer (score 0):

also error whith headers.set but I use also interceptors and this is code:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataServiceService } from './data-service.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
//inj:Injector;

  constructor(public inj: Injector,public router:Router) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   const auth = this.inj.get(DataServiceService);
   const authToken = auth.getToken();
   const clonedRequest = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+authToken)
            .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json' )
            .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST,GET,PUT,DELETE')
        });
   console.log(clonedRequest);


    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

console.log of clonedRequest display Authorization with Bearer ... token jwt but I have also error

Comment: read this blog you will understand what you are doing wrong, https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/

Comment: @Adil I read this blog and i set Authorization with example in this blog but also error .. in inetrptors when console of headres I have authorization with Bearer jwt token but response is 401 :(

Comment: i was able to solve my same problem after reading and follow this blog & i did. maybe your issue is different that i am unable to understand or solve.

Comment: @Adil thank you but with interceptors authorization is fill

Comment: and one more thing, keep your interceptor.ts and services separated.